# Why LinkedHashMap in collections dont have put method like HashMap and TreeMap?

Tags: java, collections

//***there should be put the method in interfaces of LinkedHashMap();***

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer,Integer> set=new LinkedHashMap<>();
        set.put(5,6);
        System.out.println(set);
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, LinkedHashMap does have a `put` method as your example shows...

Comment: no no, that method was inherited, but I got my point clear. thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is there.  If you compile code using it, it will work fine.

It may be confusing that [it doesn't have its own section in the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), but that is normally the case with methods inherited from a supertype.  `LinkedHashMap` inherits its implementation of `put` from its supertype `HashMap`, and you can see that in the section "Methods inherited from class `java.util.HashMap`".

Comment: ok thank you so much, I got my point clear.

Comment: Hey, will you please tell me, how the object gets printed without using the toString method?

Comment: It [does](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)) use the `toString` method.

Answer (score 1):

`LinkedHashMap` can use the put method from the `HashMap` class since it is a subclass of Hashmap, view the documentation for more information: [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) and [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)